# dynamically change fontWeight on a legend item Highcharts

Tags: fonts, highcharts, legend

I was wondering how I can change font and font weight when I double click the one of the legend items

```
function(chart){


$.each(chart.series, function(i, serie){

    $(serie.legendItem.element).bind('dblclick', function(){
       selectedSerie =  serie.index;

        // -----HERE------
        chart.legend.allItems[selectedSerie].update({fontWeight: 'bold'

        });


    })

})
```

here is it in fiddler row 160

http://jsfiddle.net/94bas/2/

Answer (score 1):

Unforntaltey this option is not possible, because border will be not adapted.

Comment: is it possible to change font color instead? or anything else on that legend item so you can tell which ones is "selected" ?

Comment: Yes that will work now I can highlight the selected one with fontWeight bold and that will work great. fontWeight will persist as it is not set by highchart so it's perfect. thanks